# How to create a custom function that returns data to multiple cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I need to create a custom function in Google Apps Script that will allow me to input the location of certain cells and then the function would output into new cells.  This is what I tried sofar:

```
function SetRange(RowNum) {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  sheet.getActiveCell(),setValue(45)
  sheet.getRange(RowNum,24),setValue(51);

  }
```

I get the error that "SetValue is not defined.  I am building this program as I learn so there are some facts that veteran programmers would know that I do not.   Thanks again for all your help

Comment: It should be `.setValue(45)` not `,setValue(45)`. Note the use of period rather than comma.

Comment: I fixed that and got the following:Error
You do not have permission to call setValue (line 6).

Comment: I see you are writing a custom function! Custom functions can only modify the cell they are being called from. More details [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values)

Answer (score 1):

Custom functions could return an array of values but can't use setValue() or setValues().

Example

```
function demo(){
  var output = [
    [1,2],
    [3,4]
  ]
  return output;
}
```

If we add `=demo()` to A1, the result will be:

```
  |  A  |  B  |
--+-----+-----+
 1|    1|    2|
 2|    3|    4|
```