# Google Script runs but get 'do not have permission to call setValues' returned as function

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

In google sheets, I am trying to return an array of results to an array of cells with a single custom function. Much like the "=IMPORT..." or "=QUERY" native functions.  Thanks to user [Bardy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333107/bardy) and this [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052890/google-apps-script-how-to-copy-array-of-objects-to-range/41056694#41056694), I have developed the following script.

```
function asset() {  
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var ss = s.getActiveSheet()
  var sc = ss.getActiveCell()
  var items = [{Description:'Well',ItemId:'1'},
{Description:'House',ItemId:'2'}];

  var outputRows = []
  var headings = ["Description","ItemId"]

  items.forEach(function(item){
    outputRows.push(headings.map(function(heading){
      return item[heading] || '';
     }));
  });

  if (outputRows.length){
    outputRows.unshift(headings);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,outputRows.length,outputRows[0].length).setValues(outputRows);
  }
}
```

The scrip works like a charm when I run it, but if I try to call the function from the spreadsheet, I get the vicious

'ERROR:You do not have permission to call setValues (line 18).'

I've scanned the blogs and checked just about every help file, and something isnt connecting.  I think it has something to do with the way I try to activate the cell, but what am I missing?

Note i am aware of similar posts like ["No Permission to call setValues() - Google Apps Script, JSON data [duplicate]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806930/no-permission-to-call-setvalues-google-apps-script-json-data)
 (marked as a dupliacte of ["No permission to call msgBox in Google Apps Scripting
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506105/no-permission-to-call-msgbox-in-google-apps-scripting)) however i believe my application is a bit different. I AM trying to allow end users to drop the results anywhere in the sheet based on the position of the entered formula.

I think it has something to do with the way I try to activate the cell.  I cant seem to figure out how to make it relative to the location of the entered formula. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the function from the script editor you can use the function `.setValues()` . However, when you using the function as custom function, you can only set values to the cell that has the custom function or its neighbouring cells. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464414/how-to-create-a-custom-function-that-returns-data-to-multiple-cells) by Ruben pretty much sums up how to set values when using custom function.

Similarly in your case instead of using `setValues()` you just return the array.
Like so:

```
function asset() {  
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var ss = s.getActiveSheet()
  var sc = ss.getActiveCell()
  var items = [{Description:'Well',ItemId:'1'},
{Description:'House',ItemId:'2'}];

  var outputRows = []
  var headings = ["Description","ItemId"]

  items.forEach(function(item){
    outputRows.push(headings.map(function(heading){
      return item[heading] || '';
     }));
  });

  if (outputRows.length){
    outputRows.unshift(headings);
    return outputRows
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much!